# How do I stop decimals changing to integers when replacing the numbers of a row in an array?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to replace the 0th row of array "A" with 0.5 times the 1st row plus the original 0th row with the code below:

```
A = np.array([[ 9,  6,  7,  8,  1,  7,  2], [ 8,  2,  6,  5,  1,  5,  3], [ 7,  3,  1,  4,  5, 10,  1],
              [10,  5,  7,  5,  4,  6,  2], [ 5,  5,  2,  6,  4,  2,  7]])
b = A[0]+0.5*A[1]
print(b)
for n in range(len(A[0])):
    A[0][n] = b[n]
A
```

The list "b" is what I want to replace the old 0th row with. However, in the new version of array A, it takes the list of decimals "b" and makes them integers but I want them to stay as decimals:

```
[13.   7.  10.  10.5  1.5  9.5  3.5]

array([[13,  7, 10, 10,  1,  9,  3],
       [ 8,  2,  6,  5,  1,  5,  3],
       [ 7,  3,  1,  4,  5, 10,  1],
       [10,  5,  7,  5,  4,  6,  2],
       [ 5,  5,  2,  6,  4,  2,  7]])
```

How do I make it so the new row's numbers stay as decimal numbers?

Comment: You can make the dtype  of `A` `float` by adding `dtype=float` when you create the array. See: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

Comment: `numpy` arrays are homogenous, **they are arrays**. When you multiply by `0.5`, the resulting array is of a floating point dtype, but your `A` array is of an integer dtype. When you assign to `A`, it will try to convert to an integer dtype. Probably  you want to just convert `A` to a floating point dtype.

Comment: Not that it solves your int/float problem, but why do you do whole row calculations with `b = A[0]+0.5*A[1]`, but then do an iterative copy.  Why not `A[0,:] = b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `A`'s original `dtype` is `int`, then every value in it is and will be an `int`. To fix it, you can specify `dtype = float` from the beginning:

```
A = np.array([[ 9,  6,  7,  8,  1,  7,  2],
       [ 8,  2,  6,  5,  1,  5,  3],
       [ 7,  3,  1,  4,  5, 10,  1],
       [10,  5,  7,  5,  4,  6,  2],
       [ 5,  5,  2,  6,  4,  2,  7]], dtype = float)

A[0] += A[1]/2
```

**Output**

```
A
array([[13. ,  7. , 10. , 10.5,  1.5,  9.5,  3.5],
       [ 8. ,  2. ,  6. ,  5. ,  1. ,  5. ,  3. ],
       [ 7. ,  3. ,  1. ,  4. ,  5. , 10. ,  1. ],
       [10. ,  5. ,  7. ,  5. ,  4. ,  6. ,  2. ],
       [ 5. ,  5. ,  2. ,  6. ,  4. ,  2. ,  7. ]])
```